# cscope adds home directory twice to a file and can't find it

Tags: cscope

When choosing a location suggested by `:cs find s`, the home path is appended twice as seen in the picture so cscope can't recognize it.

```
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels): 4E429: File "/home/dafna/media_tree//home/dafna/media_tree/blabla" does not exist
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[image]

Comment: Could `pwd` have something do with this?

Comment: Hi, I run vim from `~/media_tree` which is also where the cscope files are located